# Matlab - looping through pushbuttons (= tiles in a maze)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, uicontrol

I am building a 5 by 5 maze in Matlab, made of pushbuttons (each pushbutton is a tile in the maze). The beginning tile is green; the end tile is yellow. Open tiles are white and blocked tiles (the walls) are blue. Colors are preallocated through a 5 by 5 matrix (A), being white=0, blue=1, yellow=2 and green=3. 
My main function sets up a 5 by 5 matrix A and then calls a function "create_maze":

```
A = [0 3 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 ; 1 0 0 0 1; 1 1 0 0 1; 1 0 2 0 0];
create_maze(A)
```

The function also makes only some tiles visible, the ones around the green tile.

So far so good. Now I would like to click on a white tile and have the adjacent tiles appearing. **I would like to build a callback function that loops through all the pushbutton/tiles (so I'll need to write only one function).** 
I have put all the pushbuttons in a matrix L and managed to set a callback function to it. **The program does run without error (so the callback is kind of working) but... nothing happens!** I don't understand why. If you could have a look I would really appreciate it!

This is my function create_maze:

```
function create_maze(A, varargin)
```

I set the screen:

```
scr = get(0, 'screensize');
f1 = figure(1);
set(f1, 'menubar', 'none');
set(f1, 'position', [scr(1) scr(2) scr(3) scr(4)]);
```

create 25 pushbuttons (sorry...)

```
h1 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'String', '',...
    'Position', [200 200 100 100]);      
h2 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [300 200 100 100]);
h3 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [400 200 100 100]);
h4 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [500 200 100 100]);
h5 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [600 200 100 100]);
h6 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [200 300 100 100]);
h7 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [300 300 100 100]);
h8 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [400 300 100 100]);
h9 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [500 300 100 100]);
h10 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [600 300 100 100]);
h11 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [200 400 100 100]);
h12 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [300 400 100 100]);
h13 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [400 400 100 100]);
h14 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [500 400 100 100]);
h15 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [600 400 100 100]);
h16 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [200 500 100 100]);
h17 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [300 500 100 100]);
h18 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [400 500 100 100]);
h19 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [500 500 100 100]);
h20 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [600 500 100 100]);
h21 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [200 600 100 100]);
h22 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [300 600 100 100]);
h23 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [400 600 100 100]);
h24 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [500 600 100 100]);
h25 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'BackgroundColor', [0.91 0.91 0.91],...
    'Position', [600 600 100 100]);
```

put the pushbuttons in a matrix L

```
    L = [h1 h2 h3 h4 h5; h6 h7 h8 h9 h10;h11 h12 h13 h14 h15;...
    h16 h17 h18 h19 h20; h21 h22 h23 h24 h25];
```

set the colors of the pushbuttons and...

```
for i = 1: size(A,1) % rows
    for j = 1: size(A,2) % columns
        if A(i,j) == 0
            set(L(i,j),'BackgroundColor', 'w')
            set(L(i,j), 'visible', 'off')
        elseif A(i,j) == 1
            set(L(i,j),'BackgroundColor','b')
            set(L(i,j), 'visible', 'off')
        elseif A(i,j) == 2
            set(L(i,j),'BackgroundColor','y')
            set(L(i,j),'String','GOAL')
            set(L(i,j), 'visible', 'on')
        elseif A(i,j) == 3
            set(L(i,j),'BackgroundColor','g')
        end
    end
```

...make only some pushbuttons visible (the ones around the green one):

```
    for i = 1: size(A,1) % rows
        for j = 1: size(A,2) % columns
            if (1 < i) && A(i-1,j) == 3 ||...
                    (1 < j) && A(i,j-1) == 3                        
                set(L(i,j), 'visible', 'on')
            elseif (i < length(A)) && A(i+1,j) == 3 ||...
                    (j < length(A)) && A(i,j+1) == 3
                set(L(i,j), 'visible', 'on')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

set the callback to the matrix L

```
 set(L(i,j),'callback',{@my_funct,L,A});
```

set up the callback function

```
 function [] = my_funct(source, callbackdata,L,A)
```

The following is the complete loop that should make the tiles adjacent to the tile I clicked on visible, but nothing happens (I don't get any error either).

```
 for i = 1: size(A,1) % rows
        for j = 1: size(A,2) % columns
            if (1 < i) && A(i,j) == 0 ||...
                    (1 < j) && A(i,j) == 0                        
                set(L(i,j-1), 'visible', 'on')
            elseif (1 < i) && A(i,j) == 0 ||...
                    (1 < j) && A(i,j) == 0                        
                set(L(i-1,j), 'visible', 'on')
            elseif (i < length(A)) && A(i,j) == 0 ||...
                    (j < length(A)) && A(i,j) == 0
                set(L(i+1,j), 'visible', 'on')
            elseif (i < length(A)) && A(i,j) == 0 ||...
                    (j < length(A)) && A(i,j) == 0
                set(L(i,j+1), 'visible', 'on')
            end
        end
end  
end  
end
```

Comment: If you only want to toggle visibility of squares next to the one you've just clicked on, why are you looping across all rows and columns?

Comment: Because I would like to be able to change the original A matrix, to create new mazes automatically. Therefore I would not now which pushbutton the user is clicking on. I also want to make this possible only for white tiles and not for blue tiles. But maybe you are right and that's unnecessary. Is there a faster way to achieve that result (toggle visibility of squares next to the one you've just clicked on)?